# Trying to get property of non-object Error in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I searched a lot for a solution for this problem but I couldn't find anything useful.
I have these routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'post'], function(){
    Route::get('{id}', 'PostsController@show');
    Route::get('create', function(){
        return 'ok';
    });
});
```

When I try to access http://localhost:8000/post/create/ I get this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myblog\resources\views\post.blade.php)
```

but my post.blade.php shows any post correctly without any problems.
Have any idea why I get this error?

Notice: The get route which uses show method in PostsController works correctly an it uses post.blade.php without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

The laravel is taking '/create' as the {id} parameter and this 'create' as a parameter is going as a argument to the show() method inside PostsController.
This is happening because '{id}' route is coming in first order then the 'create' route in routes file.

There are 2 ways to solve this problem...

1. Move your 'create' route above the '{id}' route.
2. If you work in an intelligent way you can specify the parameter id (if its numeric) like this...

By specifying pattern matching in the route for the id parameter

```
Route::get('{id}', 'PostsController@show')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

move the "create" route above the '{id}' route,in your case it's not working as it's calling the "show" method on your PostsController,because "create" string is recognizing as a "{id}" pattern

Comment: Thanks a lot it works
But I wanna understand why it's been recognizing ut as a {id}?!

Answer (score 0):

It's considering 'create' as a parameter to {id}.

Restructure the route. It will work.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'post'], function(){
    Route::get('create', function(){
        return 'ok';
    });
    Route::get('{id}', 'PostsController@show');
});
```

Comment: I restructured it like that
Route::group(['prefix'=>'post'], function(){
 Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
  Route::get('create', 'PostsController@create');
 });
 Route::get('{id}', 'PostsController@show');
 
});
but I got this error:
Method App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::create() does not exist
despite it's existed

Comment: You added middleware auth. The syntax is right. Once check the middleware auth.